# Is it possible to split XML into multiple HTML pages with page navigation?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have an XML document in which there are multiple levels of Chapter's so I tried to split them into separate HTML files and also I tried to create a TOC (Table of Contents) HTML file (toc.html), from there I need to navigate/link them to their corresponding HTML files.

Note:
The ID which generated in toc.html have the same file name as the separated HTML files which generated.

**This is the XML**

```
<root>
<main>
    <chapter>
        <num>Chapter1</num>
        <heading>ChapterOne</heading>
        <notes>
            <note>
                <heading>1A</heading>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            </note>
            <note>
                <heading>1B</heading>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            </note>
            <note>
                <heading>1C</heading>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            </note>
        </notes>
        <chapter>
            <num>Chapter1A</num>
            <heading>ChapterOneA</heading>
            <notes>
                <note>
                    <heading>1A</heading>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                </note>
            </notes>
        </chapter>
    </chapter>
    <chapter>
        <num>Chapter2</num>
        <heading>Chaptertwo</heading>
        <notes>
            <note>
                <heading>2A</heading>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            </note>
        </notes>
    </chapter>
    <chapter>
        <num>Chapter3</num>
        <heading>ChapterThree</heading>
        <notes>
            <note>
                <heading>3A</heading>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            </note>
        </notes>
    </chapter>
    <chapter>
        <num>Chapter4</num>
        <heading>ChapterFour</heading>
        <notes>
            <note>
                <heading>4A</heading>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            </note>
        </notes>
    </chapter>
    <chapter>
        <num>Chapter5</num>
        <heading>ChapterFive</heading>
        <notes>
            <note>
                <heading>5A</heading>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            </note>
        </notes>
    </chapter>
</main>
```

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
<xsl:template match="/root/main/chapter">
    <ext:document href="toc.html">
        <html>

        <head></head>

        <body>
            <div class="main">
                <xsl:for-each select="/root/main/chapter">
                    <div>
                        <xsl:attribute name="class">Level_1</xsl:attribute>
                        <a href="#{generate-id()}">
                            <xsl:value-of select="num" />
                            <xsl:value-of select="heading" />
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <xsl:for-each select="chapter">
                        <div>
                            <xsl:attribute name="class">Level_2</xsl:attribute>
                            <a href="#{generate-id()}">
                                <xsl:value-of select="num" />
                                <xsl:value-of select="heading" />
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </div>
        </body>

        </html>
    </ext:document>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/root/main/chapter">
    <ext:document href="{generate-id()}.html">
        <html>

        <head></head>

        <body>
            <xsl:for-each select=".">
                <div>
                    <xsl:attribute name="id">
                        <xsl:value-of select="generate-id(.)" />
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <h2 class="headinglevelOne">
                        <xsl:value-of select="num" />
                        <xsl:value-of select="heading" />
                    </h2>
                    <xsl:for-each select="*[starts-with(local-name(), 'notes')]">
                        <div class="notes">
                            <ul class="note">
                                <xsl:for-each select="*[starts-with(local-name(), 'note')]">
                                    <li><b>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="heading" /></b></li>
                                    <li>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="p" />
                                    </li>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </div>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </body>

        </html>
    </ext:document>
</xsl:template>
```

To

**toc.html**

```
 <div class="main">
    <div class="level_1"><a href="#id_one">Chapter1 ChapterOne</a></div>
    <div class="level_2"><a href="#id_one_a">Chapter1 ChapterOne</a></div>
    <div class="level_1"><a href="#id_two">Chapter2 Chaptertwo</a></div>
    <div class="level_1"><a href="#id_three">Chapter3 ChapterThree</a></div>
    <div class="level_1"><a href="#id_four">Chapter4 ChapterFour</a></div>
    <div class="level_1"><a href="#id_five">Chapter5 ChapterFive</a></div>
</div>
```

**id_one.html**

```
<h2>Chapter1 ChapterOne</h2>
<div class="notes">
    <ul>
        <li>1A</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>1B</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>1C</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
    </ul>       
</div>
```

**id_one_a.html**

```
<h2>Chapter1 ChapteroneA</h2>
<div class="notes">
    <ul>
        <li>1A</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
    </ul>   
</div>
```

**id_two.html**

```
<h2>Chapter2 Chaptertwo</h2>
<div class="notes">
    <ul>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
    </ul>   
</div>
```

**id_three.html**

```
<h2>Chapter3 Chapterthree</h2>
<div class="notes">
    <ul>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
    </ul>   
</div>
```

**id_four.html**

```
<h2>Chapter4 Chapterfour</h2>
<div class="notes">
    <ul>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
    </ul>   
</div>
```

**id_five.html**

```
<h2>Chapter5 Chapterfive</h2>
<div class="notes">
    <ul>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
    </ul>   
</div>
```

Comment: So what is your question? You say you tried - how was your result different from the expected?

Comment: @michael.hor257k, when trying this the html files generating with a random file name which doesn't go for the navigation from toc.html (href="#id_one")

Comment: If you change `<a href="#{generate-id()}">` to `<a href="#{generate-id()}.html">` it should match the file name generated in `<ext:document href="{generate-id()}.html">`, no? It will use generated ids so they will differ from the `id_four.html` scheme you have shown. I am not quite sure from which data you wanted to compute those file names with the scheme `id_four.html`.

Comment: I am confused by your use of `#` when trying to point to another document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can try this 2.0**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="main" mode="toc"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="main" mode="chapter"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="main" mode="toc">
        <xsl:result-document href="toc.html" method="html">
            <html>
                <head>
                    <title>TOC</title>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <div class="main">
                        <xsl:for-each select="/root/main/chapter">
                            <xsl:element name="div">
                                <xsl:attribute name="class">
                                    <xsl:value-of
                                        select="concat('level_', count(ancestor-or-self::chapter))"
                                    />
                                </xsl:attribute>
                                <xsl:element name="a">
                                    <xsl:attribute name="href">
                                        <xsl:value-of
                                            select="lower-case(concat('id_', substring-after(heading, 'Chapter'), '.html'))"
                                        />
                                    </xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="num, heading"/>
                                </xsl:element>
                            </xsl:element>
                            <xsl:for-each select="chapter">
                                <xsl:element name="div">
                                    <xsl:attribute name="class">
                                        <xsl:value-of
                                            select="concat('level_', count(ancestor-or-self::chapter))"
                                        />
                                    </xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:element name="a">
                                        <xsl:attribute name="href">
                                            <xsl:value-of
                                                select="lower-case(concat('id_', replace(heading, '(([A-Z])([a-z]+))(([A-Z])([a-z]+))([A-Z])', '$4_$7'), '.html'))"
                                            />
                                        </xsl:attribute>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="num, heading"/>
                                    </xsl:element>
                                </xsl:element>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </div>
                </body>
            </html>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="main" mode="chapter">
        <xsl:for-each select="chapter">
            <xsl:result-document
                href="{lower-case(concat('id_', substring-after(child::heading, 'Chapter')))}.html"
                method="html">
                <html>
                    <head>
                        <title>Chapter</title>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        <h2>
                            <xsl:value-of select="num, heading"/>
                        </h2>
                        <xsl:for-each select="notes">
                            <div class="notes">
                                <xsl:for-each select="note">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="heading"/>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="p"/>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </div>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </body>
                </html>
            </xsl:result-document>
            <xsl:for-each select="chapter">
                <xsl:result-document
                    href="{lower-case(concat('id_', replace(child::heading, '(([A-Z])([a-z]+))(([A-Z])([a-z]+))([A-Z])', '$4_$7')))}.html"
                    method="html">
                    <html>
                        <head>
                            <title>Chapter</title>
                        </head>
                        <body>
                            <h2>
                                <xsl:value-of select="num, heading"/>
                            </h2>
                            <xsl:for-each select="notes">
                                <div class="notes">
                                    <xsl:for-each select="note">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>
                                                <xsl:value-of select="heading"/>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <xsl:value-of select="p"/>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </div>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </body>
                    </html>
                </xsl:result-document>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @sandeep kamboj, we're transforming XML through python so we are not getting the results, but after installing saxon9.jar it works! thank you for the solution